# How to override property in Reboot.css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to override `box-sizing: border-box;` property, but it still remains same.

I've already tried to use inline css like: `box-sizing: initial !important;` , but it didn't work.

As I saw in inspect element, source code shows something like this:

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

UPDATE:

I have included bootstrap from cdn.

Comment: here is working code:https://jsfiddle.net/1zyfsmp9/

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @coops I'm just studying bootstrap and I want to overwrite properties in reboot.scss, which has `box-sizing: border-box;` as default and changes it back everytime, I'm trying to modify it.

Comment: @לבנימלכה Thanks, but I know, how to write desired code as CSS, but It seems impossible, to change content of reboot.scss

Comment: @GugaNemsitsveridze see example with reboot:https://jsfiddle.net/o780w4tv/

Comment: also see here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#box-sizing

Comment: have you tried to use like unset!important

Comment: If you remove that, you will most likely break the way bootstrap works as it adds padding to the divs with a set width.  Also you will most likely get your site looking different in different browsers - is there a particular reason to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: I already tried it, but as I guess, It's completely depended on specifics of reboot.scss

Comment: You can add where you place custom code so, It's overriding box-sizing: border-box;   property. If you get difficulty can you place your code so, we can check what's the issue